# Enumerated data and vector error: expression must be a modifiable lvalue

Tags: c++, vector, lvalue, enumerated-types

I am getting the error on the lines where I am inputting "title" and "Author." I'm not quite sure what to do to fix this.

```
struct bookStruct
 {
    char title[40];
    char author[40];
    int pages;
    int year;
  };

  enum menu { display=1, add, end} ;

  void displayOptions();
  void displayBooks();


int main(){

    vector<bookStruct> book(11);
    string option;

    book[0].title = "a";
    book[0].author = "b";
    book[0].pages = 23;
    book[0].year = 21;

    displayOptions();
    cin >> option;

    displayBooks(book);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't assign to an array, you have to copy to it:

```
std::strcpy(book[0].title, "a");
```

---

But since you are using C++, I suggest you use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) instead of character arrays:

```
struct bookStruct
{
    std::string title;
    std::string author;
    int pages;
    int year;
};
```

Then you can use normal assignment like you try to do now.

Comment: thanks. The only reason I am using char arrays is because that is what the assignment dictates.

Comment: @user2105982: If you must use arrays, then make sure you use `strncpy`, or check the length yourself before copying. `strcpy` will stomp all over memory, causing horrible bugs, if the string you're copying is longer than the destination array.

Comment: @MikeSeymour On the other hand, `strncpy` might not add the terminating `'\0'` character, so it's kind of dangerous too.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Indeed; perhaps I should have said "use `strncpy` correctly according to its documented behaviour, checking its return value and handling truncation in a sensible manner", rather than abbreviating it to "use `strncpy`".